# Grails GORM Query with Multiple Objects?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to write a query in Grails to return a set of results from a domain class, but within those return the relevant results of a separate class whom have the parentId of the main class.

```
    def query = Cars.where {
        (colour == 'red') 
    }
```

And then within each list item include the set of parts relating to that CAR ID (as an example of what I'm trying to achieve, I know the code is incorrect though....

```
    query.each{ 
          this car. add(Parts.whereCarID{it.id})
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define your domain model properly, you should get it without a criteria involved.
As far as I understand you need to add `static hasMany = [parts: Parts]` in your Cars domain class, and `static belongsTo = [car:Cars]` in your Parts class.

So for example, here how it might look:

```
class Cars {
    string colour
    static hasMany = [parts:Parts]
    // ... rest of your properties 
}

class Parts {
    static belongsTo = [car:Cars]
    // ... rest of your properties 
}
```

And to get your result just do this:

```
def cars = Cars.findAllByColour('red')
```

Then you can do:

```
cars.each { car->
    println car.parts // <-- all the parts for each car is here

}
```